# Requesting an updated email address when primary email address is bouncing or has unsubscribed

Tags: email

Here is the problem we encountered. Our user unsubscribed using their primary email address(we think it's because of the marketing email) or simply got bounced. However, they still need to receive email notifications for other information.

Currently the design flow is once they login, we redirect them to a landing page requesting an updated email address. When provided, the user will be instructed to look for an email. A link in the email would re-activate the account. The user should not be able to go to the dashboard until the activation is complete.

I am just wondering are we re-inviting the wheel or is there any existing or standard solution out there?

Thank you!

Comment: IMO it seems like a bad practice to force them to resubscribe after they just unsubscribed. I would try to find a way to allow the user to unsubscribe from just marketing emails or find another way to send notifications so that they don't need email.

Comment: Or maybe use a soft approach of using notification on the header to remind the user instead of forcing them to resubscribe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing things or your question is not clear. The common approach (let's say *"the wheel"*) is to have 2 processes: **one for the user unsubscribing to your marketing mails** (a different discussion, but if this happens periodically, you're probably losing customers because you're infuriating users) and the other for the **user not being an user of your site/service anymore**.

These processes are absolutely different, so **they don't need to update any mail**: they're clearly telling you *"OK, I want to use your service, I just don't want your spam anymore, it's too annoying"*. Thus, it's easy to see that if you ask for another mail account, you'll be causing stress and a lot of friction. Just imagine the following scenario:

> **company A:** sending advertisement like mad
>
> **user of company A:** requesting NOT to receive any more unsolicited advertising
>
> **company A:** soft deletes mail account and requests another account to send unsolicited advertising
>
> **ex-user of company A:** .....

## In short...

**Nobody likes spam.** Not a single person in the world. Furthermore, **you're legally entitled to STOP** if requested. So if someone requests to be removed from your advertising mail list, just comply, you'll only win by not reinventing that wheel

Comment: This. The processes need to be considered entirely different. When a user unsubscribes from your marketing email they should still recieve **important** notifications. If you unsubscribe from say Amazon marketing mail you will still receive your order confirmations. The trick it you must make sure you're not mixing marketing into those important emails.